# Powershell not accepting variables for Get-Mailbox CMDLET

Tags: email, powershell, exchange-server

I am just curious if anyone else is having this issue today. I've tried on a couple of machines and get the same results.

1) `Get-Mailbox first.last@domain.com` = Functional as usual

2) `foreach($mb in $mbs){Get-Mailbox $mb.SMTP}` = Returns an error that 'first.last@domain.com' cannot be found.

I have verified that `$mb.SMTP` is actually first.last@domain.com and, as indicated in the error, there are no spaces or unusual characters. I've even tried `$smtp = $mb.SMTP` and verified the SMTP is correct and without spaces and the errors are the same. I then tried the filter with the same techniques and it returned an error stating

> "Property PrimarySmtpAddress does not support Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ExistsFilter. Only Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ComparisonFilter is supported."

I am under the impression that they changed something, and I was hoping to get some feedback from others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($mb in $mbs){Get-Mailbox $mb.SMTP.trim()}
```

if that works, it means that you've got trailing whitespace in the SMTP property of those $mb objects that's making the `Get-Mailbox` fail.

Comment: False, I have verified there is no trailing whitespace and also the error indicates as such by saying it could not find 'first.last@domain.com' versus 'first.last@domain.com '.

Comment: Oddly enough, Trim Works, though there are no spaces. Weird, but thanks!

Comment: @LittleKing there might not be spaces but there could be other characters. Trim removes whitespace. You might see an answer using something like this on one of the string `[int[]][char[]]($mb.SMTP)`

Comment: @mjolinor Actually, yes. I remember this issue that I had a long time ago. I retrieved the list of these SMTP's from a table embedded in an email. If they came from an Excel spreadsheet or a Word document, no problem. But there is some sort of metadata that attaches to these fields (html?) when coming from an email table. In the past I have ended up pasting the list into Excel as a middleman to get rid of this formatting before pasting into a CSV. However, the trim option is much easier if I knew where it came from. Thanks for the helpful advice, I thought I was going crazy.

Comment: @mjolinor - yes, [int[]][char[]]($mb.SMTP) reveals an extra integer at the end of that array, versus the array displayed when just a variable stored with the smtp address is manually entered. Awesome trick.

Comment: As @Matt noted, "whitespace" can be more than just spaces.  In my experience I have run into the same symptoms you posted many times and I can't remember any time that it wasn't being caused by some kind of non-display "whitespace" character or characters being attached to the values.  Running them through .trim() first has always cleaned them up.